# Is this a Google Earth Engine bug when zooming in the Map.Layer?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm starting to construct some algorithms from scratch to calculate terrain parameters. My first algorithm is about the gradient slope (radians) and it apparently looks fine when zoomed out:

[image: My slope]

The result is also quite similar to the ee.Terrain.slope algorithm. The differences in intensity are only due to layer styles.

[image: ee.Terrain.slope result]

However, when zooming in into the image to check for small changes related to resolution, I found the following strange situation:

[image: zooming into my slope result]

Which is very different from the ee.Terrain.slope, over the same region:

[image: zooming into gee slope]

I don't know why this is happening and I think it can be a bug.
The full code is attached below, where its possible to compare the results from both the algorithms. The style for ee.Terrain.slope is custom 0-90, while my slope product is stretched by 2 sigmas.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b4c5c74aad4f7237a2185a6d607b42ba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by using ee.Image.resample after calculating the kernel indices and derivatives of the terrain. According to documentation:

> resample(mode):
>   An algorithm that returns an image identical to its argument, but
>   which uses bilinear or bicubic interpolation (rather than the default
>   nearest-neighbor) to compute pixels in projections other than its
>   native projection or other levels of the same image pyramid.

Which was resolved by:

```
var DEMDerivatives = addPDerivative(DEMIndices);
var DEMDerivatives = DEMDerivatives.resample();
```